# Vim - pass register to operator function

Tags: vim

I'm trying to implement ChangePaste operator. It should replace text with the one from register.

It's working fine with motions, so I can use `cp<motion>` and the text will be replaced from default register.

Now I would like to be able to use it with different registers. I'm looking for information how to pass selected register to operator function. So, if one type `"acpiw` I would like the script to replace an inner word with register `a` content. Is that possible at all?

Code so far:

```
nmap <silent> cp :set opfunc=ChangePaste<CR>g@ 
function! ChangePaste(type, ...)
    if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use '< and '> marks.
        silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>\"_c" . @"
    elseif a:type == 'line'
        silent exe "normal! '[V']\"_c" . @"
    elseif a:type == 'block'
        silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]\"_c" . @"
    else
        silent exe "normal! `[v`]\"_c" . @"
    endif
endfunction
```

*Edit:*

Solution using v:register and buffer variable:

```
nmap <silent> cp :let b:changepaste_buffer = v:register<cr>:set opfunc=ChangePaste<CR>g@ 
function! ChangePaste(type, ...)
    if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use '< and '> marks.
        silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>\"_c" . getreg(b:changepaste_register)
    elseif a:type == 'line'
        silent exe "normal! '[V']\"_c" . getreg(b:changepaste_register)
    elseif a:type == 'block'
        silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]\"_c" . getreg(b:changepaste_register)
    else
        silent exe "normal! `[v`]\"_c" . getreg(b:changepaste_register)
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: `:help v:register`

Comment: Inside the ChangePaste function it is always set to `"`.
As a workaround, I used buffer variable to store the last register and then getting value from that variable. See edit.

@romainl can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) in the comments, you can access the `v:register` variable in your function.

No need to even save it as a buffer variable.